# Xcode error - lipo: can't move temporary file: (is a directory)

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm getting this error on my project suddenly and can't find why its happening. Tried clean, delete Release folder, restart Xcode... still getting the error on compilation.

`error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't move temporary file: /Users/myhome/dev/juce_projects/MyApp/Builds/iOS/build/Release/MyApp.app/MyApp to file: /Users/myhome/dev/juce_projects/MyApp/Builds/iOS/build/Release/MyApp.app/MyApp.lipo (Is a directory)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure`

This on Xcode 7 OS X 10.11
The app combines JUCE C++ and Objective-C & Swift.

Comment: Have you tried ⌥⇧⌘K ?

Comment: Try deleting Xcode preferences

Comment: defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with completely different libraries, whilst Swift (2.2 and Xcode 7.3). However, I was able to get rid of the problem.

My problem was with the CleanroomASL Swift framework. I linked and embedded the CleanroomLogger framework in my project. The latter requires the CleanroomASL framework. I used the General Settings of my project target to insert both framework.

Then all of the sudden this "lipo" error message appears. I noticed that I had many choices of which CleanroomASL iOS framework I could add. When I tried one that appeared to have a much longer file path than all the other embedded frameworks, I finally got rid of the error.

So bottomline is that there is no problem in the cache, nor in the "lipo" tool, nor with admin rights. I found similar problem on StackOverflow, but these had all to do with either CocoaPods or Carthage packages. In one I read something about nested dependency. In my case there was also a nested dependency (CleanroomLogger framework must have CleanroomASL to compile).

My hint is to look for nested dependency, and try to avoid these.